# Swagger - Jersey - Tomcat (Not able to generate swagger.json, shows 404 : Not found)

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I am new to swagger and jersey.
My api operations are working fine.
 I followed the steps in the link: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5 to add swagger into my api.  When I give my try to access the swagge.json via the url:http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/swagger.json I get 404 -Not found. Here are my api codes.
 Can you please help me out with this.

1. pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vishwas</groupId>
    <artifactId>messenger</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>messenger</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>messenger</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

2. web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,
                com.vishwas.messenger
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Swagger Configuration</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vishwas.messenger.sevlet.SwaggerConfigurationServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    

</web-app>
```

3.Beans config class for swagger

```
package com.vishwas.messenger.sevlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;

public class SwaggerConfigurationServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setTitle("Messenger Api documentation");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/messenger/webapi");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.vishwas.messenger.resources");
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }

}
```

[output screenshot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLx83.png

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem, I changed the swagger-jersey2-jaxrs artifact version to the latest one and also installed the compile dependencies along with it which was provided in the maven repository website.
Please check the version properly!!